# No se ejecuta la función de manera correcta, ya que no devuelve el valor deseado

Tags: c, funciones

Solo tengo problemas en las funciones con dos variables, por que no lee un dato y me arroja 0

```
#define SALIR 5
#include <stdio.h>
// definimos funciones 
int menu ();
float calcularArea (int tipoFigura);
float triangulo (float base, float altura);
float cuadrado (float lado);
float rectangulo (float largo, float ancho);
float circulo (float radio);
void imprimirArea(float area);

int main(){

int opcion;
float superficie;

//proceso
do{
opcion=menu();
if (opcion != SALIR){
superficie=calcularArea(opcion);
imprimirArea(superficie);
}
printf("\nPRESIONE <ENTER> PARA CONTINUAR...");
fflush(stdin);
getchar();
}while(opcion!=SALIR);

return 0;
}


//funcion menu
int menu () {
int tipoFigura;
printf("AREAS FIGURAS GEOMETRICAS:\n");
printf("    1. TRIANGULO\n");
printf("    2. CUADRADO\n");
printf("    3. RECTANGULO\n");
printf("    4. CIRCULO\n");
printf("    5. SALIR\n");
printf("TECLEE OPCION: ");
scanf("%d", &tipoFigura);
return tipoFigura;
}
```

Este error pasa en el case 1 o case 3, los otros se desarrollan  de manera correcta

```
 float calcularArea(int tipoFigura) {

switch ( tipoFigura) {
    float area;
   case 1: {
      float base, altura ;
      printf ("CALCULA E IMPRIME EL AREA DE UN TRIANGULO\n");
      printf("PROPORCIONE LA BASE: ");
      scanf("%f", &base);
      fflush(stdin);
      printf("PROPORCIONE LA ALTURA: ");
      scanf("&f", &altura);
      fflush(stdin);
      area=triangulo(base, altura);
      break; }
      
   case 2:{
      float lado;
      printf ("CALCULA E IMPRIME EL AREA DE UN CUADRADO\n");
      printf("PROPORCIONE EL LADO: ");
      scanf("%f", &lado);
      fflush(stdin);
      area= cuadrado (lado);
      break; }
```

En esta caso ya no realiza la funcion, por que me delvuelve el valor 0, cuando le doy largo y ancho, pero al parecer solo se lee el valor largo, y el ancho lo toma como 0, y por eso me sale el 0 como resultado

```
      case 3: {
      float largo, ancho;
      printf ("CALCULA E IMPRIME EL AREA DE UN RECTANGULO\n");
      printf("PROPORCIONE EL LARGO: ");
      scanf("&f", &largo);
      fflush(stdin);
      getchar();
      printf("PROPORCIONE EL ANCHO: ");
      scanf("%f", &ancho);
      fflush(stdin);
      getchar();
      area=rectangulo (largo,ancho);
      break; }
      <
   case 4: {
     float radio;
      printf ("CALCULA E IMPRIME EL AREA DE UN CIRCULO\n");
      printf("PROPORCIONE EL RADIO: ");
      scanf("%f", &radio);
      fflush(stdin);
      area=circulo (radio);
      break; }
      
   case 5:{
        break;} 
  }
  }
 float triangulo(float base, float altura){
 float areaTrian;
    
 areaTrian= base*altura;
 return areaTrian;
 }

 float cuadrado(float lado) {
 float areaCuadra;
     
 areaCuadra=lado*lado;
 return areaCuadra;
 }
```

Esta es la funcion que no se ejecuta bien, lo que intente es borrar un dato "ancho" y multiplicar dos veces "largo" y si se ejecuta de manera correcta

```
 float rectangulo (float largo, float ancho) {
 float areaRect;
 
 areaRect=largo * ancho;
 return areaRect;   
 }

 float circulo (float radio){
 float areaCir, pi;
 pi=3.1416;
 
 areaCir=pi*(radio*radio);
 return areaCir;
 }
```

Se imprime el valor 0 en cualquier de esos dos casos (1 o 3), pero si es alguno de los otro si se imprime el valor correcto

```
void imprimirArea(float area){
printf("EL AREA ES:     %.2f", area);
}
```

Comment: ¿Y en que lenguaje estas trabajando?

Comment: Según las declaraciones y sintaxis parecer ser C. Lo editaré y seleccionaré ese lenguaje para darte una respuesta. De lo contrario, pulsa el botón de editar tu post y puedes cambiarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios errores críticos, la mayoría en la función `calcularArea()`

**[1]** Los `case` de los `switch` no llevan llaves:

```
switch(tipoFigura) {
    case 1:
        // ...codigo;
        break;
    case 2:
        // ... codigo
        break
    // ...
}
```

**[2]** Corregir `scanf("&f", &altura)` en `case 1` y `scanf("&f", &largo);` en `case 3`
Debe ser `"%f"`.

**[3]** Quita todas las definiciones de variables que hay dentro de `switch` y `case`.
Podrías definirlas como:

```
float calcularArea(int tipoFigura) {
    float area=0.0, base, altura, lado, largo, ancho, radio;
// ...
```

De lo contrario, al menos mi compilador, emitirá el siguiente error:

```
error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
```

**[4]** La función está declarada como `float`, pero no está retornando ningún valor.

```
float calcularArea(int tipoFigura) {
    // ...
    return area; // <- agregar esto
}
```

**[5]** Pudo ser un error de tipeo, pero veo un signo `<` sobrante entre el `case 3` y `case 4`
**[5.1]** Hay unos `getchar();` innecesarios en el `case 3`

**[6]** Finalmente en la función `triangulo()`, el área debe ser:

```
areaTrian = (base * altura) / 2;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió muchooo